# msi installer error

Tags: installshield, uninstallation

I get the following error when I tried to uninstall a software. I tried with multiple uninstallers, but nothing worked. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1001 Errors are always the result of an InstallUtil custom action.  Either you added a component and set the .NET Installer Class attribute to true or you consumed a merge module that has a custom action.

These custom actions are truely horrible and you should refactor your installer to not need the custom action or use a WiX DTF custom action instead.

Comment: I can not rewrite the installer, because it is not created by me. Could you please suggest any uninstaller to uninstall the software....

Comment: I rewrite installers that I didn't author all the time.  That's why Windows Installer supports transforms. In this case you have to update the cached MSI so you can uninstall.  Look me up if you want some help.